# sortable angular material table

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i have a angular material table . i want add `sortable` option in my table .i do some actoin but it not worked .

this is my data source :

```
export class ArticleCommentDataSource implements DataSource<any> {


constructor(private articleCommentService: ArticleCommentService) {

}

loadNewsComment(
    pageIndex: number,
    pageSize: number,
    filters: TableFilterRules[]
): void {

    this.articleCommentService.GetAll(this.searchParam)
        .pipe(
            catchError(() => of([])),
            finalize(() => this.loadingSubject.next(false))
        )
        .subscribe((gift: TablePagingIndex<Comment>) => {
            const data = gift.records;
            this.articleCommentLengthSource.next(gift.totalCount);
            this.articleCommentSubject.next(data);
        });
}


connect(): Observable<any[] | readonly any[]> {

    return this.articleCommentSubject.asObservable();

}

disconnect(): void {

    this.articleCommentSubject.complete();

    this.loadingSubject.complete();

}
```

}

and this is my html :

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort class="mat-elevation-z8">
<!-- Position Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> No. </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
  </ng-container>
</table>
```

and this is my `ts file :

```
dataSource: ArticleCommentDataSource;
@ViewChild(MatSort, {static: true}) sort: MatSort;
```

my `DataSource` not have `sort` property .

**how can i put sortable in my table ????**

Comment: sortData is defined on MatTableDataSource<T>

Comment: @NicoD how can i sort by this way ?

Comment: Have you imported `MatSortModule` into your module?